# Retrieving CellRange from xslx golang

Tags: excel, go

trying to get some hands-on with golang. Currently I have an issue which I can fix using java but not with go. 
Here is the issue. I have to read an excel file, and just get a Area Reference for example cells (Sheet1!A1:F6) and not the entire sheet.
This can be easily achieved using Apache Poi, but all the api's that go has do not have a way to get a range of cells. The golang library I am using is https://godoc.org/github.com/tealeg/xlsx . I would really appreciate if anyone has done this kind of work. Unfortunately I dont have a working code for go since I don't know the function I have to call. Other than go over all the columns and then ensure just get the ones I need.